# How to set a static IP in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

How do I set my computer to have a static IP in Ubuntu 11.04? The only two lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I think usually when people do this they have a wired connection and just edit the eth0 settings, however I'm using a wireless adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Network Manager with a static IP address.

If you want a system-wide setting, you can use `/etc/network/interfaces` for a wireless adapter. The only difference with a wired adapter is that you'll need extra settings for the encryption (unless your wifi network is unencrypted).

For WPA (any supported variant), use [wpa-supplicant](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wpasupplicant) [Install wpasupplicant http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wpasupplicant).

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.0.2.255
    gateway 192.0.2.1
    dns-nameservers 192.0.2.2
    wpa-ssid chez-jackson
    wpa-psk swordfish
```

The `wpa-` parameters are those you could put in a block in [`wpa_supplicant.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.html), with `wpa-` prefixed.

For WEP, the [wireless-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wpasupplicant) [Install wpasupplicant http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wpasupplicant) package has all you need. Instead of the `wpa-` settings, put [`wireless-` settings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/wireless.7.html), e.g.

```
    wireless-essid chez-jackson
    wireless-key 0123456789abcdef
```